# auto populate corresponding data into different input fields after selecting a value to one input field javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have al horizontal form which is being generated dynamically using javascript, and each input field has a jquery auto complete which populates data from DB using $.get method.

I want to fill data to 2nd input field with the corresponding value when I select a data to first input field. Here the rows are being cloned and then the autocomplete functionality is also being cloned along with the rows.

In the image below, if I select the category set then I want the value field to be populated automatically:

[image]

I am able to achieve the auto complete but not able to achieve to fill data to second input field.

```
function loadcategorysetvalue(table,tabdata){
    var catsetlov=[];
    var catvalov=[];
 $.get("URL",function(response){
    catsetlov=response;
    }).done(function(){
        var row =null;
        var newId=1;
        for(var i=0;i<catsetlov.length;i++){
        newId++;`enter code here`
        row=insertrow(table(table,tabdata,"categories");
        cell=row.cells[0];
        cell.children[0].value=catsetlov[i];
        setcatvalue(catsetlov[i]);
        addbtn(row);
        var id = cell.children[0].getAttribute("id");
        var newId=(id+"_"+newId);
        cell.children[0].setAttribute("id",newId);
        $('#'+newId).autocomplete({
            source:catsetlov,
            minLength:0
         }).focus(function(){
           $.get("url",function(response){
           catsetlov=response;
        });
          $(this).autocomplete("search","");
       });
      }
    });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could set the others input fields on "select/change" event of the autocomplete field, see following example please:

```js
var mySource = [{"label":"Value one","id":"1"},{"label":"Value two","id":"2"},{"label":"Value three","id":"3"}];

$("#txtAutocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: mySource,
  select: function(event, ui){
    if(ui.item){
      $("#hiddenField").val(ui.item.id);
      return ui.item.label;
    }
    else{
      $("#hiddenField").val('');
    }
  },
  change: function(event, ui){
    if(ui.item){
      $("#hiddenField").val(ui.item.id);
    }
    else{
      $("#hiddenField").val('');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>
  Start type something like "Val.."
</p>

<input type="text" id="txtAutocomplete">
<input type="text" id="hiddenField" disabled="disabled">
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: thankQ @alessandro but the problem is both of the fields are having independent $.get calls and they are two different arrays :(

Comment: like array a[1,2,3,4,5,6] and array b[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]

Comment: Can't you add in "catsetlov" all the information that you need?